# Running native applications on the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, unix, kernel, linux-distributions, c

When the Linux kernel has loaded it loads the distro or OS to take over, how can I make the kernel load some native application (written in c) instead? I don't need a GUI or anything, Instead I want to (gradually) build on this application to make it a full blown OS, that's why I don't want an OS, I want **Just the kernel** to execute my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires to understand the linux booting mechanism a little bit better.

After booting, the kernel initializes the device drivers, and after that it starts the first process on the system. By default, it is `/sbin/init`. From this point, the kernel doesn't do anything by own, only executes the requests of the processes.

You can override this default setting by an `init=/path/to/your/binary` in the kernel boot parameters. These parameters you have to give to your bootloader (which is probably [grub](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html)).

If you want a simple command prompt with a shell, you can give `init=/bin/bash` to your boot loader.